# Simple circuit or component for output specific voltage in specific interval

Tags: timer

I am a newbie to electronics and trying to learn some basics. Is there is any simple circuit or component which can output 5 V in every specific interval (10 sec). Just output and turn back off. I am using this as an interrupt from a custom sensor into Arduino.

I found something like 555 timer IC. But is it something for that purpose?

Comment: What do you mean by "turn back off" and "custom sensor"? Is it part of the circuit design or just for testing it?

Comment: Yea.. like its testing purpose.. If this iterrupt is coming, the system can decide the device is active.. just a buzzer system.. Sorry friend.. just some beginner stuff

Answer (score 0):

Your 555 will be fine if it is powered from 5 V and the common GNDs are connected.

It would probably be much better to power your sensor from an *output* pin of your micro-controller whenever required. That way your program knows when to read the sensor via an *input* pin and avoids getting invalid data due to reading when the sensor is off.

```
// Pseudo code.
main{
  sensorPower(true);           // Power up the sensor.
  delay(500);                  // Wait for it to power up and stabilise.
  x = readSensor(0);           // Read analog 0.
  sensorPower(false);          // Power down the sensor.
  delay(9500);                 // Wait for the remainder of the 10s.
}
```

Note that the delay() instruction is usually a terrible programming practice as your micro can do nothing else while waiting. Use a timer instead but that's beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: Sorry if so we need a second arduino. isnt it.. 
Its only like some testing purpose.. If this iterrupt (5v in interval) is coming, the system can decide the device is active.. just a buzzer system.. Sorry friend.. just some beginner stuff

Comment: No. You use the one micro-controller to do everything. That's the whole idea. Maybe you need to rewrite your question.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but my understanding is that you want to simulate an external sensor to test your actual program in the Arduino. Is that right?

If it is, the quickest solution is probably to use another Arduino. You can then use the flexibility of the programming to change the timing values if you need to test any other configuration.

If you don't want to buy a second Arduino, you can get a cheap ATtiny and program it via the Arduino and the Arduino IDE. There are many tutorial online which show how to do it.

Otherwise, the 555 IC will probably do the job too.